# Clients do not get software updates from Configuration Manager

Tags: sccm-2012

I am a beginner in the SCCM administration and I wish to bring your expertise.

**Issue:**

Clients do not get software updates from Configuration Manager
I deployed Windows updates to my Desktop collection(Windows 10 and 7) Using ADR. In this case, I see in In Progress section only Non-Compliant status. I ran many times the Software Update cycle on client, but no changes.

**System Informations :**

SCCM 2012 R2 SP1,WSUS and  BD installed on same machine (Windows server 2012 R2/ SQL Server Management studio 2012)

**Notes:**

- Software centre is not showing any update however updates are available on SCCM
- There are no errors in UpdatesDeployment.log, UpdatesHandler.log, UpdatesStore.log, WUAHandler.log, or WindowsUpdate.log
- on the clientLocationServices.log \ WUAHandler.log both indicated the correct SUP was being targeted for scanning. Furthermore, those scans were taking place successfully after doing Software Updates Scan Cycle .
- UpdatesDeployment.log indicated the following:

`Assignment ({xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}) already in progress state (AssignmentStateDetecting). No need to evaluate UpdatesDeploymentAgent’
Evaluation initiated for (0) assignments.
‘EnumerateUpdates for action (UpdateActionInstall) – Total actionable updates = 0`

- WSUS Synchronization version Catalog: MinSourceVersion = ContentVersion
- I have refresh compliance state using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc146437.aspx  ( Creating an UpdatesStore instance by using the UpdatesStore COM class and the RefreshServerComplianceState method).
- No Deadline for installation or reboot.

**- GPOs:**

- 01- Configure Automatic Updates policy -> Disabled
- 02- Specify Intranet Service of Update Service -> managed by SCCM (no GPO enforced)
- 03- Allow Signed Updates from a Microsoft Update Service Intranet Location -> Enabled

below some logs.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Esg8UKXnDbTO5NlgkGdVviEVBm_CJHV/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd recommend not to upload these logs in full to the internet without erasing all the sensitive information.

Your clients have trouble establishing a connection to WSUS:

WindowsUpdate.log:

```
2018/10/01 11:21:42.5844495 35852 35556 Misc            [0]8C0C.8AE4::10/01/2018-11:21:42.584 [endpointproviders]Got WSUS SimpleTargeting URL: http://CEVSCM0201.Cevital.com:8530""
2018/10/01 11:21:42.5845408 35852 35556 IdleTimer       [0]8C0C.8AE4::10/01/2018-11:21:42.584 [agent]WU operation (CAuthorizationCookieWrapper::InitializeSimpleTargetingCookie) started; operation # 10; does<NULL> use network; is<NULL> at background priority<NULL>
2018/10/01 11:21:42.5845416 35852 35556 ProtocolTalker  [0]8C0C.8AE4::10/01/2018-11:21:42.584 [agent]Initializing simple targeting cookie, clientId = ef36c302-a0ad-4314-a6f1-9dc45757c453, target group = <NULL>, DNS name = cevlap2646.cevital.com
2018/10/01 11:21:42.5845420 35852 35556 ProtocolTalker  [0]8C0C.8AE4::10/01/2018-11:21:42.584 [agent]  Server URL = http://CEVSCM0201.Cevital.com:8530/SimpleAuthWebService/SimpleAuth.asmx
2018/10/01 11:21:42.5845442 35852 35556 WebServices     [0]8C0C.8AE4::10/01/2018-11:21:42.584 [webserviceinfra]Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2018/10/01 11:21:42.5922144 35852 35556 WebServices     [0]8C0C.8AE4::10/01/2018-11:21:42.592 [webserviceinfra]WS error: Une erreur s??est produite lors de la communication avec le point de terminaison sur ?? http://CEVSCM0201.Cevital.com:8530/SimpleAuthWebService/SimpleAuth.asmx ??.
2018/10/01 11:21:42.5922152 35852 35556 WebServices     [0]8C0C.8AE4::10/01/2018-11:21:42.592 [webserviceinfra]WS error: Le serveur a renvoy?? un code d????tat HTTP ?? 407 (0x197) ?? avec le texte ?? Proxy Authentication Required ??.
2018/10/01 11:21:42.5922155 35852 35556 WebServices     [0]8C0C.8AE4::10/01/2018-11:21:42.592 [webserviceinfra]WS error: Le proxy n??cessite le sch??ma d??authentification HTTP ????n??gocier????.
2018/10/01 11:21:42.5923488 35852 35556 WebServices     [0]8C0C.8AE4::10/01/2018-11:21:42.592 [webserviceinfra]Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot my issue is resolved , my package wasn't ditributed correctly.

Comment: @hadjer.yh if I could help you I'd be very happy if you would mark the answer as correct :)